# css style not working properly for column element

Tags: css

I'm trying to show some 'card' element in two columns. But box-shadow of last element of first column and first element of second column not rendering properly. The problem is, it looks like there is a boundary where every column starts and ends except start of the first column and end of the last column.

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.16.0/css/mdb.min.css");

.container-masonry {
  -webkit-columns: 2 200px;
  -moz-columns: 2 200px;
  columns: 2 200px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container-masonry .card {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid !important;
  page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  break-inside: avoid-column !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container p-4">
  <div class="container-masonry">
    <div class="card mb-4 text-dark">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
        Departments
      </div>
      <div class="card-body text-muted">
        Department List Empty
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 text-dark">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
        Departments
      </div>
      <div class="card-body text-muted">
        Department List Empty
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 text-dark">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
        Departments
      </div>
      <div class="card-body text-muted">
        Department List Empty
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 text-dark">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
        Departments
      </div>
      <div class="card-body text-muted">
        Department List Empty
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I got:
[image]

Comment: CSS will try to divide up to content and spread it, so I think this is relatively expected. I can't tell you if there's a clean fix, but you can perhaps remove the `box-shadow` on each box, and instead apply a `filter: drop-shadow()` to your container.

Comment: your bits of code do not show your issue :(

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I've added bootstrap to this snippet, please check again.

Comment: okay; it seems to be with Chrome , you may try : `.container-masonry .card {
  margin-top:2px;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}`  break rules never worked with column CSS ;)  Possible fix with BS4 classes https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjYrNyJ